# Dividing a square into three equal parts, using ruler and compass only

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

Is it possible to divide a square into three parts of equal area, using ruler and compass only? If so, how do you do it?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "three equal parts". If you trisect any side (entirely doable), this allows you to divide a square into three rectangles of equal size and area.

Comment: Yes, I mean three parts of equal area. I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Can someone kindly explain what I'm doing wrong? I tried following all the rules, and this is a genuine (if basic) math question. Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's doable. Consider the illustration below for side $AB$ of your square,

[image]

where you draw circles of radius $r=\overline{AB}$ centered at both $A$ and $B$ and connect their crossing points $E$ and $E'$, yielding the midpoint of segment $\overline{AB}.$

Then draw three circles of radius $r_2=\frac{\overline{AB}}{2}$, centered at $A$,$B$ and the midpoint from above. Connect the top crossing point $E$ with $C$ and $D$, the two bottom crossing points of the smaller circles. This trisects segment $\overline{AB}$ into $\overline{AP_1}$, $\overline{P_1P_2}$ and $\overline{P_2B}.$

Repeat for segment $\overline{CD}$ in your square $ABCD$, and connect the trisection points $P_1P_3$ and $P_2P_4.$ Done.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you know how to draw a line perpendicular to another line through a point on it (classic problems you shall be able to solve in order to use the as "lemmas"), just easily go through the steps [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yjjRtkZkU24), you can mark all the important points on the sides using your ruler or compass. (I've done so and could solve the problem.)
Hope this helps you :)